# PHPDocumentor `-d` results in empty documentation, but `-f` is working as expected

Tags: php, phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

- I have my PHP codes in folder called src.
- That src folder is in folder called lib.
- My documentation will be in lib/docs.
- So, both src and lib are located in the same folder.

Now when I am generating the documentation:

- I tried: `php phpDocumentor.phar -f ../pdk/Something.php` and it works fine!
- I tried: `php phpDocumentor.phar -d ../pdk` but it does not work, the documentation is generated but it is empty. Not even Something.php got its documentations generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug -- https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/1930

Should be solved in next release.

Workaround is to execute phpdoc in a directory so that the `-d` arg is `-d .`